# Baseline alignment of VTextField and VSelect

Tags: vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I often want to create small form with a text field or a select input followed by a button. But I am really struggling to get these things aligned, especially if there is a hint or error message that goes with the VSelect or VTextField.

The problem seem to be that VSelect and VTextField don't play nice with a baseline alignment. To demonstrate, see this code.

```html
<div style="display: flex; align-items: baseline; margin-block: 1em; outline: 1px solid green; gap: 10px">
  <div>Baseline</div>
  <v-text-field variant="outlined" label="Text Field" hint="some hint" persistent-hint />
  <v-select variant="outlined" label="Select" hide-details="auto" />
  <v-btn @click="pressButton">Add</v-btn>
</div>
```

[image: Misaligned text and selects]

I would expect the text of the button to align with the text in the text field. Am I misunderstanding baselines? Or, have I done something wrong with the CSS? Or, is this a bug or failing in Vuetify? I didn't want to open an issue when I don't quite understand if this is a bug or not, so asking here first.

Answer (score 1):

#### Reflection to `v-input`

Unfortunately, the `v-input` class is a grid where the input field occupies the first row and the hint occupies the second row. As a two-row element, the CSS calculates the center of the `grid` as the `flex-container`'s center point. This is why the "Baseline" and "Add" button align perfectly.

[image: v-input grid]

#### Solution

**If you want to insert anything in front of the input field, you can use the `prepend` template.** In this case, behind the scenes, the previously mentioned 1-column 2-row grid will expand to a 2-column 2-row grid.

[image: v-input grid with prepend]

Similarly, **you can also insert anything behind the input field using the `append` template element.** In this case, Vuetify actually manipulates the grid columns once again.

[image: v-input grid with prepend and append]

**By using these**, you can achieve inserting the text "Baseline" in front of the first input field and placing the "Add" button behind the last input field.

#### Example

```js
const { createApp } = Vue
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify

const vuetify = createVuetify()

const app = createApp()
app.use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.3.1/dist/vuetify.min.css">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.3.1/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-container>
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="6" sm="6">
        <v-text-field variant="outlined" label="Text Field" hint="some hint" persistent-hint>
          <template v-slot:prepend>
            Baseline
          </template>
        </v-text-field>
      </v-col>
      <v-col cols="6" sm="6">
        <v-select variant="outlined" label="Select" hide-details="auto">
          <template v-slot:append>
            <v-btn @click="pressButton" hide-details="auto">Add</v-btn>
          </template>
        </v-select>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</div>
```